# Java Arrays binarySearch() insertion point

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

As per Java doc for Arrays.binarySearch(int[] a, int key)

> Returns:
>
> index of the search key, if it is contained in the array;
> otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as
> the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index
> of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements
> in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this
> guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key
> is found.

I need to understand why its returning `(-(insertion point) - 1)`, why not just `-(insertion point)`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because if it returned `-(insertion point)`, and the insertion point was 0, then you would not be able to distinguish between *I found it, it's at index 0*, and *I haven't found it, you can insert at index 0*.

Answer (score 9):

Consider an array:

```
int intArr[] = {5,12,20,30,55};
```

now consider these two binary search statements:

```
System.out.println("The index of element 5 is : " + Arrays.binarySearch(intArr,5));
```

and

```
System.out.println("The index of element 4 is : " + Arrays.binarySearch(intArr,4));
```

**Output**

```
The index of element 5 is : 0
The index of element 4 is : -1
```

because of that  `-1`, we can differentiate between the two outputs. If there was no `-1` then both of these statements would have given the same output, i.e., `0`.